# Knockout ko.utils.arrayFirst always returns null

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I can't figure out why this always returns null. even when text box value has new value.

```
   self.update = function (data, event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.type === "blur") {
            console.log(self.getPercentById(event.target.value)); // always null
        }
        return true;
    };
    self.getPercentById = function (percent) {
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.List(), function (item) {
            return item.Percent() === percent;
        });
    };
```

ViewModel

```
    function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.url = ko.observable(document.URL.substr(document.URL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
        self.activeSort = ko.observable();
        self.sortColumn = null;
        self.selected = ko.observableArray()(false);
        self.allSelected = ko.observable(false);
        self.selectedItem = ko.observable(null);
        self.List = ko.observableArray();
        self.sort = function (items, event) {
...
```

Comment: Are you sure that the value in the text box matches some value in self.List()?

Comment: yes. when I tried this it works: return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(item.Percent()) === percent; but I don't think this is the right way of doing it. why would I need to unwrap it?

Comment: That depends on the structure of your List. Can you show the code where it is defined?

Comment: Your last comment Shane implies that the Percent observable in each list element stores an observable itself, hence you need to unwrap it again